# what is the meaning in C++ when casting both (int) and (int16_t)

Tags: c++, arduino

I am studying a C++ code in Arduino example for reading external data.
The code use casting (int16_t) and also (int).

int16_t is fixed integer type, but I don't understand it's purpose in the code.

```
_vRaw[0] = (int)(int16_t)(Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8);
```

Is there any difference if I write like below?

```
_vRaw[0] = (int)(Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8);
```

Comment: Your title and question text asks about C but the code shown and the tags show you are asking about C++. C and C++ are different languages. There are no member functions like `.read()` in C.

Comment: There is not definition of `_vRaw` nor `Wire` please post a [mre]

Comment: Probably casting it to 16-bit discards the uppermost bits. But there's nothing we can tell for sure without more context.

Comment: Depends on the definition of `int` on your target. I'd rather guess, the outer cast to  `(int)`  is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written code like this before so I can explain the purpose of the cast to `int16_t`.

The Arduino command `Wire.read()` generally returns a number between 0 and 255 representing a byte read from the I2C device.

Sometimes, two of the bytes you read from a device will represent a single signed 16-bit number using [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).  So, for example, if the first byte is 1 and the second byte is 2, we want to interpret that as a value of 1 + 2*256 = 513.  If both bytes are 255, we want to interpret that as -1.

Let's assume that your code is being compiled for a system where `int` is 32-bit (almost any 32-bit microcontroller), and both bytes are 255, and think about this expression:

```
(Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8)
```

The value of this expression would simply be `255 | (255 << 8)` which is 65535.  That is bad; we wanted the value to be -1.

The easy way to fix that bug is to add a cast to `int16_t`:

```
(int16_t)(Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8)
```

When we cast 65535 to an `int16_t` type, we get -1 because an `int16_t` cannot hold 65535 (it can only hold values from -32768 to 32767).  (The C++ standard does not guarantee that we get -1, but it is implementation defined behavior so you can check the [manual of your compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation) if you want to make sure.)  If we later cast it back to an `int` (either with an explicit cast or by setting some `int` equal to it), the compiler will do the correct signed extension operation and give us an `int` with a value of -1.

By the way, I'm not confident that your compiler will run the two calls to `Wire.read()` in the right order unless you have a semicolon between then.  Also, the final cast to `int` is probably not needed.  So I would rewrite the code to be something like this:

```
uint8_t lsb = Wire.read();
_vRaw[0] = (int16_t)(lsb | Wire.read() << 8);
```

Comment: May be worth noting that `Wire.read()` return type is `int`, rather than, as one might expect, `char`. Thus, 255 safely fits there and doesn't get interpreted as -1.

Comment: thanks for the detail explanation, they are very informative. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `(int16_t)` cast will truncate the value to 16 bits. The `(int)` cast does nothing, unless `_vRaw[0]` has a type that is implicitly convertable from `int` but not `int16_t`, which is very unlikely.

In all probability, `Wire.read()` returns `char`, and neither of these casts do anything, because `(Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8)` is already an `int` expression that fits within 16 bits.